# Geomean of large numbers with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate the geomean of some large numbers. Problem is that the result of the product of large numbers is overflow. Example:

```
a = array([168116745,168117411,168117729,168118170,168118695,168119286,168119610])
print(a.prod())
print(a.prod()**(1.0/len(a)))
```

Output

```
1947451320
21.235703778668626
```

On the other hand it is possible to use the rule of `sqrt(a.b) = sqrt(a).sqrt(b)`. Therefore, I can write

```
n = 1.0/len(a)
temp = []
for i in len(a):
    temp.append(i**n)
```

So, I have the partial numbers and I am able to find the product of `temp` elements. I am looking for a more efficient and smaller code based on the existing libraries. Any idea for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use logarithms. Try this:

```
a = array([168116745,168117411,168117729,168118170,168118695,168119286,168119610])
print('GM =', np.exp(np.average(np.log(a))))
```

Alternatively, scipy has a [dedicated geometric mean function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gmean.html).

Comment: The result is different from excel with `GEOMEAN()`.

Comment: Which of these two approaches did you take? Also, how much of a difference is there between the Excel answer and the python answer?

Comment: One possible reason for a difference is [floating point arithmetic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/).